# Databricks SSl issue. Getting not opening SSL root certificate

Tags: ssl, databricks, cluster-computing, workflow, databricks-cli

i am facing this issue , We need to restart the cluster manually when init script get executed. So that script will get initialized to all the nodes in cluster. That time we don't see the ssl issue.When job starts that time cluster should get restarted by itself after init script execution. it is not happening right now. i tried with restart command as well it is not working.

getting below error when i am executing the notebook as part of scheduled job/workflow
Below is the error:org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Could not open SSL root certificate file /dbfs/FileStore/server-ca.pem

%sh databricks clusters restart --cluster-id 0314-060130-2j50a7zj

it is not working.

Please help us how do i restart the cluster through code.